# How to use use precompiled static libraries with MinGW?

Tags: c, linux, windows, gcc, mingw

I am trying to use MinGW to compile Linux project into Windows. I have been successful doing so with Cygwin, but I would match rather prefer to use MinGW so I the program does not end up having dozens of unnecessary dependencies.

Unfortunately, I have run into a problem that the compiler complains of unidentified references to the file. I am using a precompiled version of FFTW3 for Windows and using dlltool to create .a files to link it to MinGW. I have specified the libpath for the compiler, but unfortunately, I am still encountering errors.

Here is my output:

```
make all 
gcc -I../Include -L..\Lib  -Wall -O3  -o lvdoenc lvdoenc.o lvdomain.o  -I../Include -L..\Lib -m32
lvdoenc.o:lvdoenc.c:(.text+0x29b): undefined reference to _imp__fftw_execute'
lvdoenc.o:lvdoenc.c:(.text+0x608): undefined reference to_imp__fftw_malloc'
lvdoenc.o:lvdoenc.c:(.text+0x647): undefined reference to _imp__fftw_plan_r2r_2d'
lvdoenc.o:lvdoenc.c:(.text+0x8d1): undefined reference to_imp__fftw_free'
lvdoenc.o:lvdoenc.c:(.text+0x8e5): undefined reference to _imp__fftw_destroy_plan'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: lvdoenc.o: bad reloc address 0x20 in section.eh_frame'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [lvdoenc] Error 1
```

13:23:28 Build Finished (took 217ms)

All the solutions I have come across involve compiling using gcc to link fftw3 (-lfftw3), but this does not work in MinGW. I am having the same problem in the Cygwin, but that solution of using -lfftw3 as a compiler option does work. I have even specified the location of the lib path. The include path works just fine, but it can't find the library in the libpath.

Any help would be great appreciated.

Comment: `-lfftw3` must be given, without it the linker can't resolve the symbols from this library. You should add what's not working when you compile with `-lfftw3`. I just downloaded the dlls, used `dlltool` and tried to link a symbol of the fftw3-library with MinGW and it worked.

Comment: Does MinGW's gcc or linker know how to handle Windows style paths? Cause that's what your feeding to it (`..**\**Lib`). Also you're passing the include and lib paths twice.

Comment: Okay, so I used the Windows compiled binaries and just got it to recognize it by changing it to -lfftw3-3, it still is not linking properly. I think it can handle Windows style path because the include path is written the same way and it works just fine. @4566976 Really? where did you get the dlls from? I tried their website and the libraries would not link. I am using Eclipse as my IDE btw. Interestingly enough, some of the symbols do actually link properly, but others are not.

Comment: @4566976 I just learned some of the distributions of the libs are actually missing certain symbols. Where did you downlaod those Dlls from?

Comment: @Skylion: I downloaded them from [here](http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html). `dlltool -d libfftw3-3.def -l libfftw3.a` `int main()
{
     fftw_malloc();
}` `gcc x.c -L.\. -lfftw3`

Comment: @4566976 Thanks so much that worked. I was just using dlltool incorrectly. If you cleanup that comment and put it into an answer, I'll "accept" it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the DLLs from [here](http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html).

Then I've done the following (see http://www.mingw.org/wiki/createimportlibraries):

`dlltool -d libfftw3-3.def -l libfftw3.a`

```
/* x.c */
int main() { fftw_malloc(); }
```

`gcc x.c -L.\. -lfftw3`

Comment: Hi, I have tried the method above. Still I am getting the following error

C:\GNUstep\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lfftw3
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status